# Chroot sftp jail seems to be insistent on not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, openssh, chroot

So I followed this guide to the letter:
http://markshust.com/2013/04/01/how-setup-chrootd-sftp-account-linux
and a few other guides as well, but I seem to be incapable of getting a connection.

I am running on an Ubuntu system.

This is what I get in my auth.log:

```
Accepted password for repouser from 127.0.0.1 port 57791 ssh2
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user repouser by (uid=0)
subsystem request for sftp by user repouser
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user repouser
Connection closed by 192.168.10.191 [preauth]
```

Here is a tree print from my home dir:

```
.
├── [root     root    ]  repouser
│   └── [repouser dialogue]  public
```

My sshd_config:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group dialoguerepo
        ChrootDirectory /home/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

My /etc/passwd:

```
repouser:x:1008:1008::/public:/sbin/nologin
```

My /etc/group:

```
dialoguerepo:x:1008:
```

I have no clue what is wrong, I just get the error message connection closed, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual problem, it was a long shot, but I got something out of the dusty parts of my mind and thought about line endings. It might have been a long shot, but that was the actual problem, one of my colleagues it seems had uploaded a file in dos/windows line ending format.

So dos2unix on that file and a restart on ssh and it all magically jumped into action.

Comment: There is a minimum lay time of 48 hours until you can accept your own answers, but you are welcome to supply the answer and I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have it setup fine, but you are connecting to SSH and not SFTP. Please try connecting like this:

```
 sftp repouser@192.168.10.191
```

Comment: Why do you think so? I actually looks like he is connecting using SFTP client: `subsystem request for sftp by user repouser`